# Can we use ampersand in alias names which we use in Oracle select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Can we use ampersand in alias names which we use in Oracle select statement.
any work around to get this working?

```
select ename||','||job as name&job from employees ;
```

ps: I am using plsqldeveloper IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely possible - you have to put the identifier in quotes, and you also have to turn the substitution prompting off - either by selecting the relevant option in whichever IDE you're using, or by using set define off. E.g.:

```
set define off;

select dummy "JOB&NAME" from dual;

JOB&NAME
--------
X
```

Don't forget to set define back on afterwards, if this is part of a script.

Comment: Don't forget to educate the table designers about why using an ampersand in an object name is a bad idea!

Comment: I'm guessing that this is required for some sort of report output. I certainly wouldn't encourage its use as a permanent identifier (eg. a column name)! Ugh, I've got a headache just thinking about all the double-quotes needed in subsequent queries... *{;-)

Comment: Not to mention the Case sensitivity!